# Offsetting points from lines using SQL Server Spatial?

Tags: linear-referencing, sql-server-spatial

I'm new with SQL spatial data processing, so I'm not sure how to solve my task. I have two tables - table with lines and table with points that are located on lines. Lines and points are related by ID value. I need to create another one table with points whee location of points is shifted for specified distance off corresponding line to the left or right (defined as attribute of a point). I.e. like it is shown below.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [Tour].  I've added a tag for [tag:linear-referencing] to your question because that is what you seem to be describing.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  If so could you answer your own question?  I'm trying to find the same thing...